# Google Maps fade in InfoBox content with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps-api-3, infowindow

I have a bunch of markers on my map and I would like an image to fade in whenever you hover over each marker.

So far the InfoBox itself has no background image to appear invisible, with the jQuery effect being applied to the image once the InfoBox is open, but I can't get the effect to trigger when I use the same mouseover event to show open the InfoBox. It works when I use a 'click' event with a separate DOM listener but for some reason a mouseover event doesn't trigger it.

Here's the snippet of code that I'm trying to get to work (where ".hello" is set to "opacity:0"):

```
var infoBox = new InfoBox({myLatlng: marker.getPosition(), map: map}); 

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', function (){
    infoBox.open(map, this);
    infoBox.setContent('<div id="content"><img class="hello" src="css/images/office.png" alt="" /></div>');
    $(".hello").animate({opacity: 1},200);
});
```

Using a 'click' event instead works with a separate DomListener, but not with mouseover:

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    $(".hello").animate({opacity: 1},200);
});
```

How can I achieve the desired effect?

Comment: Can't you use the google.maps.event.addDomListener(marker, 'mouseover', function() { ..} );

Comment: Doesn't work for some bizarre reason. I've used exactly the same code as mentioned above, only replacing the word 'click' with 'mouseover', and nothing!

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with only css if you use css3 animation you can fade in the infobox.

```
.infoBox {
-webkit-animation: fadeIn 300ms; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
animation: fadeIn 300ms;
}

/* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
    from {opacity: 0;}
    to {opacity: 1;}
}

/* Standard syntax */
@keyframes fadeIn {
    from {opacity: 0;}
    to {opacity: 1;}
}
```